# drop rows in a user defined table type

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

i have the following type:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[locationTable] AS TABLE(
[location_id] [varchar](100) NULL,
[name] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[address] [varchar](100) NULL,
[latitude] [varchar](100) NULL,
[longitude] [varchar](100) NULL,
[distance] [varchar](100) NULL,
[state] [varchar](100) NULL,
[sub_cat] [varchar](100) NULL,
[idCat] [varchar](100) NULL,
[icon_link] [varchar](100) NULL,
[checkinsCount] [int] NULL
)
GO
```

and i'm passing a table as parameter having the above type to a stored procedure... but i need to delete some rows from this table in my stored procedure but i keep getting that it cannot be modified.... sql is always requesting to define the table as readonly and in this case i can not modify

Comment: sorry but question is not clear enough to be asnwered

Comment: Title says "drop columns" and description reads "delete some rows". Which one is it?

Answer (score 3):

A table parameter to a stored procedure must be readonly.  [MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Note that the READONLY keyword is required for declaring a table-valued parameter.

You can solve this dilemma by copying the content to a local table variable.  For example:

```
if exists (select * from sys.procedures where name = 'TestProc')
    drop procedure TestProc
if exists (select * from sys.types where name = 'TestType')
    drop type TestType
go
create type TestType as table (id int, name varchar(20))
go
create procedure dbo.TestProc
    @par TestType readonly
as
declare @t TestType

insert @t select * from @par

delete @t where id = 2

select * from @t
go
declare @p1 TestType
insert @p1 values (1,'a'), (2,'b'), (3,'c');
exec dbo.TestProc @p1
```